# Oracle 11g: unable to restore the scheme in XE from the EE dump

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-xe

I used `expdp/impdp` utility.

In Oracle 11g XE not all tables are restored. Here are some excerpts from the log:

```
...
ORA-31684: Object type USER:"GAZ" already exists
...
ORA-39083: Object type TYPE failed to create with error:
ORA-02304: invalid object identifier literal
...
ORA-39082: Object type TYPE:"GAZ"."T_DATASET_INFO" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type TYPE:"GAZ"."T_DATASET_INFO" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type TYPE:"GAZ"."T_FIELDVALUE_INFO" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type TYPE:"GAZ"."T_FIELDVALUE_INFO" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type TYPE:"GAZ"."STRING_AGG_TYPE" created with compilation warnings
ORA-39082: Object type TYPE:"GAZ"."STRING_AGG_TYPE" created with compilation warnings
...
ORA-39112: Dependent object type OBJECT_GRANT:"GAZ" skipped, base object type TYPE:"GAZ"."PARMS" creation failed
ORA-39112: Dependent object type OBJECT_GRANT:"GAZ" skipped, base object type TYPE:"GAZ"."T_FIELDVALUE_RECORD" creation failed
ORA-39112: Dependent object type OBJECT_GRANT:"GAZ" skipped, base object type TYPE:"GAZ"."T_DATASET_RECORD" creation failed
...
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Deferred Segment Creation
...
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"GAZ"."ACTDOCS" failed to create with error:
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Deferred Segment Creation
...
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"GAZ"."DOCUM_NOTICE" failed to create with error:
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Deferred Segment Creation
...
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Fine-grained access control
...
ORA-39083: Object type RLS_POLICY failed to create with error:
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Fine-grained access control
...
ORA-39083: Object type RLS_POLICY failed to create with error:
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Fine-grained access control
...
ORA-39083: Object type PROCACT_INSTANCE failed to create with error:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01403: no data found
...
ORA-39083: Object type PROCACT_INSTANCE failed to create with error:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01403: no data found
...
Job "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" completed with 3397 error(s) at 17:53:03
```

Does the XE edition support the format in which the EE edition serializes the schemes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several types of errors invovled. But two of them are indeed related to features that are available in the enterprise edition but not in the express edition:

```
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Deferred Segment Creation

ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Fine-grained access control
```

It will indeed not be possible to directly import these dumps. As a workaround, you can try to create the problematic tables yourself before you import the dump. Use the definition from the source system and remove or replace the unsupported features. Once the table exists, the import will issue a warning that the table already exists but it should import the data anyway if the schema is compatible.

The error about the fine-grained access control can initially be ignored. But for a produtive use, you would need to come up with another way of controlling the access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Many features of 11G EE are not supported in XE. The safest way is to add version as 10.2, to your impdp command. Example given below

```
impdp Target_schema/<password>@<DB_TNSNAME>  directory='DATA_DUMP' dumpfile=data_dump_EE.dmp logfile=import.log REMAP_SCHEMA=<Source_Schema>:<Target_schema> version=10.2
```